# puppet epp template error (Invalid EPP: Syntax error at)

Tags: puppet

I'll try migrate `erb` to `epp` and deprecated `hiera_hash` to `lookup`. 
Current error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: 
Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: 
Error while evaluating a Function Call, epp(): Invalid EPP: 
Syntax error at 'Port ' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/sshd/templates/sshd_config.epp:4:24 
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/sshd/manifests/init.pp:23:16 on node puppettestnode
```

my **init.pp**:

```
class sshd {
  #$sshd_config = hiera_hash('sshd')
  $sshd=lookup('sshd', {merge => 'hash'})

  package { 'openssh-server':
    ensure => present,
    before => Service['sshd'],
  }

  file { '/etc/ssh':
    ensure  => directory,
    owner   => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0755',
    require => Package['openssh-server']
  }->

  file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config':
    owner   => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0644',
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp("${module_name}/sshd_config.epp"),
  }~>

  service { 'sshd':
    ensure => running,
    require => [
      Package['openssh-server'],
      File['/etc/ssh/sshd_config'],
    ],
  }
}
```

**sshd_config.epp**:

```
###Managed by Puppet###

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
<% if $sshd["port"] -%>
Port <%= $sshd["port"] %>
<% else -%>
Port 22
<% end -%>

# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
<% if $sshd['listen'] -%>
ListenAddress <%= $sshd['listen'] %>
<% else -%>
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
<% end -%>
```

**common.yml**:

```
---
sshd:
  port: '22'
  listen: '0.0.0.0'
```

**puppet lookup from puppet server:**

```
puppet lookup sshd --merge unique --environment production --explain
Searching for "sshd"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Merge strategy unique
      Hierarchy entry "Per-node data"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera/nodes/puppettestserver"
          Original path: "nodes/%{::fqdn}"
          Path not found
      Hierarchy entry "Common data"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera/common.yaml"
          Original path: "common.yaml"
          Found key: "sshd" value: {
            "port" => "22",
            "listen" => "0.0.0.0"
          }
      Merged result: [
        {
          "port" => "22",
          "listen" => "0.0.0.0"
        }
      ]
```

Please help if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` statements are using a Ruby syntax rather than Puppet DSL syntax, which is causing the unusual error message.

The template should be:

```
###Managed by Puppet###

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
<% if $sshd["port"] { -%>
Port <%= $sshd["port"] %>
<% } else { -%>
Port 22
<% } -%>

# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
<% if $sshd['listen'] { -%>
ListenAddress <%= $sshd['listen'] %>
<% } else { -%>
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
<% } -%>
```

Remember that in the Puppet DSL (which EPP is very much based on), these would look like:

```
if $sshd["port"] {
  # Port
} else {
  # Port 22
}
```

so you must use the same curly braces in EPP. ([Documentation: Conditional statements](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html#if-statements)).

Comment: Many thanks, but now i have another error `Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value. at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/sshd/templates/sshd_config.epp:4:7 on node puppettestnode`

Comment: `$sshd` is undefined, you need to either use the fully qualified variable name with the class name prefix (`$sshd:sshd`) or pass it in the epp function call: `epp("${module_name}/sshd_config.epp", {"sshd" => $sshd})`. See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_template_epp.html#accessing-variables for details.

Comment: Many thanks again. Variant`epp("${module_name}/sshd_config.epp", {"sshd" => $sshd})` work fine, but for use class prefix need use double `:` as `$sshd::sshd`